# React Error Failed to execute 'getCurrentPosition' on 'Geolocation'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, openweathermap

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);
  const [long, setLong] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLocation();
  }, []);

  async function fetchLocation() {
    try {
      const position = await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      setLat(position.coords.latitude);
      setLong(position.coords.longitude);
      fetchWeather();
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async function fetchWeather() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        `${
          import.meta.env.VITE_WEATHER_API_URL
        }/weather/?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&APPID=${
          import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY
        }`
      );
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${res.status}`);
      }
      const result = await res.json();
      setData(result);
      console.log(result);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
      console.error(error);
      setError(error.message);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Weather App</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : error ? (
        <p>{error}</p>
      ) : data ? (
        <div>
          <p>Location: {data.name}</p>
          <p>Temperature: {data.main.temp} °C</p>
          <p>Humidity: {data.main.humidity} %</p>
          <p>Wind: {data.wind.speed} m/s</p>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am new to react. While running this code, I am getting an **(Failed to execute 'getCurrentPosition' on 'Geolocation': 1 argument required, but only 0 present) error.** I don't know what I did wrong. Please help if you know what is causing that problem.

i am expecting to get all the data from Openweathermap api into browser with geoLocation

Answer (score -2):

The error message "Failed to execute 'getCurrentPosition' on 'Geolocation': 1 argument required, but only 0 present" indicates that the getCurrentPosition function expects an argument, but your code is **calling it without providing any arguments**. This function expects a success callback function and an optional error callback function.
To fix this issue, you should modify the fetchLocation function to provide a success callback function. You can do this by passing a function as an argument to getCurrentPosition that will be called when the geolocation data is successfully retrieved. Here's how you could try to modify your code:

```html
async function fetchLocation() {
  try {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback);
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
    console.error(error);
  }
}

function successCallback(position) {
  setLat(position.coords.latitude);
  setLong(position.coords.longitude);
  fetchWeather();
}
```

In this modified code, I added a successCallback function that takes the position as an argument and sets the latitude and longitude states. This callback is provided to getCurrentPosition. When the geolocation data is successfully retrieved, the successCallback function will be called, and it will set the lat and long states and then call fetchWeather.